# How to get return true with jq array value

Tags: arrays, json, jq, any

I'm trying to use the following jq command to return a true output, if any of one of the condition is true in the list.

```
.Tags[] as $t| "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"| IN($t[])
```

Input

```
 {
    "Tags": [{
            "Value": "INF-D-XX-SEC-OPNV-UW1",
            "Key": "Name"
        },
        {
            "Value": "INF-D-XX-CFS-StandardInfrastructure-UW1",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
        },
        {
            "Value": "sgOpenVPNAccess",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
        },
        {
            "Value": "UW1",
            "Key": "Location"
        },
        {
            "Value": "INF",
            "Key": "Application"
        },
        {
            "Value": "D",
            "Key": "Parent Environment"
        },
        {
            "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:111111:stack/INF-D-XX-CFS-StandardInfrastructure-UW1/1111-11-11e8-96fe-11",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id"
        },
        {
            "Value": "OPNV",
            "Key": "ResourceType"
        }
    ]
}
```

This gave me a list of returned boolean values back as the following,

--output--

```
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

I would like to return a single value `true` if one of the

```
Key="aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
```

is detected and without given me a list of value back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very efficient solution (both with respect to time and space) is easy thanks to `any/2`:

```
any(.Tags[]; .Key == "aws:cloudformation:stack-name")
```

This of course evaluates either to `true` or `false`.  If you want `true` or nothing at all, you could tack on `// empty` to the above.

Comment: This is a good solution.  To add more context on my initial questions, if the above jq return "false" I would like to continue on and evaluate the json statement or else just break out of it.  Is that possible?
`any(.Tags[]; .Key == "aws:cloudformation:stack-name") | **continue to evaluate json if no result found**`

Comment: That's what `//` is for, as in the example in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the previous answer by @peak, as can't post comments, you can use the '-e' flag to jq to set the exit status so you can easily chain shell commands together. This avoids having to test for the returned string.

```
jq -e 'any(.Tags[]; .Key == "aws:cloudformation:stack-name")' json >/dev/null && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Missing'
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution , that 
   build a array of boolean from the .tags , and after use **any** to agregate all the booleans

```
jq '.Tags | map( .Key == "aws:cloudformation:stack-name" ) |  any '
```